# Retrieve Google Analytics statistics into personal website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, google-analytics

I have google analytics integrated with mobile app and I want to display some of the graphs and statistics on a dashboard I have created that is not connected to google analytics. Is there a method to fetch this data with APIs for example? I am using .Net for the dashboard.

Comment: Have you looked into Google Data Studio?

Comment: No I haven't. Could it be used to integrate analytics data into my website?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it does have APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The [google analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) will allow you to extract google analytics data.  It returns the data in the form of JSon strings.

The API itself will not format the data for you.  However you want the data displayed will be up to you.

I created these samples a few years ago [Samples C#](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#c)  Let me know if you have any issues.

```
// Create the DateRange object.
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2015-06-15", EndDate = "2015-06-30" };

// Create the Metrics object.
Metric sessions = new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" };

//Create the Dimensions object.
Dimension browser = new Dimension { Name = "ga:browser" };

// Create the ReportRequest object.
// Create the ReportRequest object.
ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    ViewId = "XXXX",
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { browser },
    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { sessions }
};

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
requests.Add(reportRequest);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

// Call the batchGet method.
GetReportsResponse response = analyticsreporting.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();
```